# Who is Dobbu Scay in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

[Mark Hamill is credited with two roles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2527336/characters/nm0000434?ref_=tt_cl_t1) in The Last Jedi: Luke Skywalker (obviously), and someone called **Dobbu Scay**

[image]

**Who is Dobbu Scay?**

Comment: It's unknown, I have a theory but I think it might be the character that Warwick Davis portrays.

Comment: Pure guesswork, but I would imagine that it's the drunk alien who shoves quarters into BB-8; https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x9DV.png

Comment: I can't find the article but apparently Mark Hamill really wanted to have a go portraying a CG character (thats the why, not the who though)

Comment: @Valorum There is a reference on imdb that corroborates your theory. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2527336/trivia?item=tr3728269

Comment: @Scot - That appears to be a fan-theory posted as fact

Comment: QuirkyByte says that the drunk alien is Warwick Davies; https://www.quirkybyte.com/blog/2017/12/cameos-totally-missed-last-jedi/

Comment: @Valorum The QuirkyByte link also later says that Hamill is another contender for the role...

Comment: @Scot - Maybe the drunk alien is both Warwick Davies *and* Mark Hamill.

Comment: @Valorum - this is how rumors begin: "Dobbu Skay: Illegitimate love-child of Mark Hamill and Warwick Davis!"

Comment: +1 for the picture taken of the movie screen.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Pablo Hidalgo has confirmed in a [twit](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/942135522322923520) that the short drunk alien who tried to play BB-8 like a slot machine was Mark Hamill's cameo, Dobbu Scay

> **Q:** *Going into viewing number 6 of #thelastjedi so I'm begging @pablohidalgo or @rianjohnson to **tell me the name of the Canto Bight patron who plays BB-8 like a slot machine.** Inquiring minds want, nay, NEED to know.*
>
> [@PabloHidalgo](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/942135522322923520):  *I'll just say this - **he's listed in the credits as the second role [that]
> someone very prominent in the cast plays.** :)*

[image]

I initially thought this might be Warwick Davies' cameo but this is the only *second role* by any main cast character.

Further confirmation (from Pablo Hidalgo) can be found here.

Comment: FYI, this is confirmed to be Hamill [here](https://youtu.be/p09c0MXDxto) (22:50).